# Clean up of memory leak in unmanaged code

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, c++-cli

I have been wandering about the best way to sandbox memory leaks in 3rd
party libraries when using them from the .Net framework.

I have a 3rd party library, written in C++/cli, that leaks a lot of memory.

Is there anyone out there who has found an elegant way of cleaning up
unmanaged memory leak using .Net?

Best regards,

Comment: The best way would be to give a bug-report to the supplier of the library, and let them fix it. Or perhaps you are just using the API wrong? Maybe you forget to call a "release" or "close" function in the API?

Comment: How would you clean it up even from non-managed code? If you have a memory leak and don't have a pointer to the memory then you can't free/delete it.

Comment: Get the library fixed? Seriously, you shouldn't rely on a broken library. Even if you could "clean up" the memory, it is likely that the library is invoking undefined behaviour.

Comment: the c++ dll code was written by me but it's a little big that's why i cant add

Comment: How do you know the leaky memory is the library's responsibility? Sounds like you've gotten too used to managed memory :) You have to study the API to figure out which memory is your responsibility, and which remains with the library.

Comment: Well, the only way to sandbox unmanaged memory from C# is to run it in a separate process. But it's still just a dirty hack :)

Comment: what if i use Marshal.ReleaseComObject

Comment: `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` will help if your C++ library is exposed to your C# library via COM - is it?

Comment: the c++ Library is a COM Object and it's used by C# as interop

Comment: Marshal.ReleaseComObject needs the object you want to relase. If you have a reference to the object then it is not a memory leak. The same applies to free/delete and whatever else there it to deallocate memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way, unless of course you can modify and fix the C++ code, but probably this is not an option. I had the same problem in the past, solution is host the leaking code in a process ( note: an app domain is **not** enough ) and shut down periodically that process. Use some IPC technique to comunicate with that process instance. You can optional create a pool of two of that process to apper reactive even when you need to shutdown a process, so you can easily switch to the other instance, already running.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a memory checker of your choosing to find the leaks. this is a pretty straight forward process. I use Intel Inspector (Part of Intel parallel studio) but others will do the trick.

In order to sandbox allocations, you can use a `malloc` replacement such as google_malloc and modify it to have a `free_all_memory` function if it doesn't already have one.

This isn't very elegant, but if your unmanaged code is in really bad shape, that's an option.

Answer (score 0):

**Unmanaged object:**
Unmanaged objects are created outside the control of .NET libraries and are not managed by CLR. Examples of such unmanaged code are COM objects, file streams, connection objects, Interop objects. (Basically, third-party libraries that are referred to in .NET code.). GC can not handle the unmanaged object by itself because it has no idea about it. So, for example, let's say you used a pointer in your C++/CLI library class, and you delete that pointer in the destructor(~) of that class. This will lead to memory leak [because, In C++/CLI, the notation ~ is already reserved for deterministic destructors (because all destructors are deterministic in C++). So, here we must use the notation ! instead](https://manski.net/2012/01/idisposable-finalizer-and-suppressfinalize/).

**C++/CLI example of IDisposable, Finalizer and GC.SuppressFinalize()**

```
ref class ClassName {
public:
  ClassName() : m_isDisposed(false) {
    m_unmanagedData = new CustomObject();
  }

  ~ClassName() {
    if (m_isDisposed)
       return;

    this->!ClassName();
    m_isDisposed = true;
  }

  // Finalizer
  !ClassName() {
    delete m_unmanagedData;
  }

private:
  bool m_isDisposed;
  CustomObject * m_unmanagedData;
};
```

**Follow this documentation guideline from Microsoft to find out the memory leak in your C++/CLI library** [Find memory leaks with the CRT library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/finding-memory-leaks-using-the-crt-library?view=vs-2019)